# CDI instance select by annotation class name

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi

i have a problem with CDI instances. In the project there is more than one JPA EntityManager. I want to annotate entites with the entity managers qualifier to use. This is the Annotation:

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ManagedEntity {
    Class<? extends Annotation> value() default BaseEntityManager.class;
}
```

My Entity is annotated with it:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TEST")
@ManagedEntity(StandardEntityManager.class)
public class MyEntity { ... }
```

Later i build some queries with this entity and just save the query context. With this context a can execute the query. What i need is a way to get the right entity manager. So i inject any EntityManager instances and tried to select the right one.

```
@Inject
@Any
private Instance<EntityManager> entityManagers;

...

// Read out the ManagedEntity and check for mixed managers
Class<? extends Annotation> manager = getQueryManager(queryContext); 

...

// Select requires Annotation
EntityManager em = entityManagers.select(... classname to annotation ...).get(); 
// ... QueryContext to query and execute here ...
```

My problem is that a do not find a way how i can get an Annotation from its classname. If i proxy a new instance cdi is not accepting it, building a AnnotationLiteral dose not work dynamicly (correct me?)

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I am aware of two options that you can use, probably someone with stronger knowledge in CDI can suggest a better one.

- [AnnotationLiteral](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/enterprise/util/AnnotationLiteral.html) based

If you have a small set of annotations, then you can make use of the AnnotationLiteral definition for this situation. As shown in the Javadoc, create a separate literal class and then pass an instance of that class to your lookup code.

- Parse the available instances

Iterate over the available instances and find the instance that matches the type that you are looking for. Once found, use that for your entity operations.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I use this way as work around. A pronounce all possible Qualifiers with an CDI event. Well its not that nice but it works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Qualifier @Any states that you need all instances of an implementation.

It doesn't matter what qualifiers they have, you want them all @BaseEntityManager, @StandardEntityManager,and so on whatever. It is possible with AnnotationLiteral, May be you have not used AnnotationLiteral correctly.

Here is proper usage

```
 public class ManagedEntityQualifer extends AnnotationLiteral<ManagedEntity>
implements ManagedEntity {

            final String name;

            ManagedEntityQualifer (String name) {
                this.name = name;
            }

            @Override
            public String value() {
                return name;
            }
        }
```

Or you can go with CDI Portable extension

[CDI Portalbe Extension](http://relation.to/12981.lace)

See these posts
 [Dynamic Dependency Injection](http://coders-kitchen.com/tag/annotationliteral/)
[AutomatedTellerMachineImpl @Inject @Any Instance to inject all transport instances](https://code.google.com/p/jee6-cdi/wiki/DependencyInjectionAnIntroductoryTutorial_Part2)